# port 6000 - что за зверь?

Tags: node.js, http, windows-10, localhost

Создал сервер на Nodejs. Решил повесить его на порт 6000, консоль выдает, что все ок - сервер запущен. Однако, браузер достучаться к нему не может. Запросы к серверу не приходят. 
Поменял порт на 3000 - все работает.
Что за дела?)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В консоле, номер порта указывается динамически

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По идее, ничего, кроме этого сервера, запущено не должно быть. И я думал, что если порт и занят, то получу ошибку. Однако, в качестве теста,запустил MongoDB на порту 27017, потом запустил сервер Nodejs на этом же порту - и никаких ошибок не увидел. Сервер работает, принимает запросы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: возможно на `6000` что-то уже висит, но сервер не выдает ошибку

Comment: @mix, дополнил вопрос. + перегрузил комп - проблема не исчезла(

Comment: операционка какая?

Comment: @mix, Windows 10.

Comment: На ошибку сереньким гляньте "ERR_UNSAFE_PORT". Это какие то происки браузера, потому что в интернете рекомендуют лечить эту проблему специальными ключами при запуске браузера. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502345/neterr-unsafe-port-in-dart

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, навели на мысль. ,Ее результат я в ответе записал

Answer (score 0):

FireFox дал самый понятный (на данный момент) ответ [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом Edge - нормально отработал...)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, только что это обнаружил у FF. IE при этом единственный кто работает. Вот бы еще список таких портов найти